# Is there any advantage at all in Swift if redundant code?

Tags: swift

```
var _name = item["name"] as NSString
```

VS

```
var _name: NSString = item["name"] as NSString
```

Is there any advantage in speed or something behind the scenes in adding the extra : NSString besides readability? If not, why keep it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any advantage in speed or something behind the scenes in adding the extra : NSString besides readability?

No. The compiler infers it anyway. Sometimes the compiler can't infer it, so it's required.

> If not, why keep it at all?

Who said you should? Don't.